# Azure-cosmosdb - unable to retrieve documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to retrieve all the documents from a collection stored in azure cosmos db.

However , after the query i get the below error

```
"MongoError: Command is not supported
    at I:\xxxxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:771:34
    at handleCallback (I:\xxxxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:178:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (I:\xxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:545:3)
    at nextFunction (I:\xxxxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:770:14)
    at I:\xxxxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:667:7
    at queryCallback (I:\xxxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:263:5)
    at I:\xxxxx\bot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:541:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)"
```

It looks like the cursor is sending this when i'm trying to convert the docs to an array `toArray()`

heres my function thats trying to retrieve the docs

```
var getQuestions = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const questionDB = state.db.db('admin')
        const program = questionDB.collection('Version')
        program.find().toArray()
            .then(function(docs){
                console.log('docs : ', docs)
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('err : ', err)
            })
    })
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you connecting to cosmos db? where is your connection string?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. CosmosDB is not fully compatible with MongoDB, hence the error.

Comment: Any updates now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue when I followed the sample code from this [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_query.asp).

***query.js:***

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://***.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true";

MongoClient.connect(url, {user: '***', password: '***'},function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("db");
  var query = { name: "jay" };
  dbo.collection("coll").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
      db.close();
  });
});
```

***error:***

[image]

Azure Mongo API doesn't support for all of MongoDB features and syntax , please refer to this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support#database-commands) to check the features and syntax which are supported by Azure Mongo API. `toArray` method is not found in that list.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: sigh .. thats sad .. so the only option is to do a forEach in the cursor object? :/